# Problem printing in LibreOffice Writer but not in Adobe Acrobat Reader or Evolution

Tags: 11.10, libreoffice

I recently upgraded to 11.10. I use an HP LaserJet P1102w printer. Since the upgrade, LibreOffice Writer does not print several letters. Adobe Viewer and Evolution do print perfectly, as before.

Nobody seems to have reported anything like that. I would welcome clues on how to tackle this puzzling behavior.

Comment: Some people in forums reported updating to the latest [hplip](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) helped solving issues with that printer model. Another idea: does printing to a CUPS PDF printer work from LibreOffice? Are other LibreOffice components (Calc, Impress) affected by this issue, too?

Comment: LibreOffice Calc prints correctly, LibreOffice Impress does miss certain letters, as LibO Writer.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem. LibO Writer calc etc wouldn’t print several characters. Seemingly random. Only a problem from LibreOffice. What fixed the problem for me was reverting from pdf to postscript print setting in LibO. File -> Printer Settings -> Properties -> Device -> Printer Language type was set to PDF so I changed it to PostScript. Had to update the normal template to make it stick.

[Here is how you change the default template (in french)](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_the_Default_Template/fr)

Unfortunately, that only helps when creating new docs. You have to manually modify each old doc, which sucks a bit...

Comment: Thank you wiCk.  What you suggest works.  Now, to make it stick, what do you do ? I've got a french version of LibO.  Hard to figure out what is what.

Answer (score 2):

It took a lot of digging, but found that you can make the change the default printer settings using spadmin shell command. I'm using Kubuntu, and that is found at `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program`. You will need to run it as `root` to get the settings to save, but it finally worked for me.