# problem running a command with incron

Tags: command-line, printing, libreoffice, pdf

I try to print some ODT documents from LibreOffice 4 (Ubuntu 13.04 OS) to a Toshiba e-Studio 167 printer. When the document has fonts like Liberation Sans, Liberation Serif, etc., I get a printed page with the next error:

```
ERROR:
invalidfont
OFFENDING COMMAND
$definefont
STACK:
--nostringval--
/WASRNP+LiberationSerif
--nostringval--
/WASRNP+LiberationSerif
--nostringval--
--nostringval--
17
```

However, if export ODT file to PDF and I print PDF file or if I print another PDF file from Acrobat, there's no problem.

I've been trying the solutions given in this threads, but if I change printer language type to PostScript, I get the same error:

[Unable to print from LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69014/unable-to-print-from-libreoffice)

[Problem printing in LibreOffice Writer but not in Adobe Acrobat Reader or Evolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68909/problem-printing-in-libreoffice-writer-but-not-in-adobe-acrobat-reader-or-evolut)

To try to resolve the problem I configured incron in order to print to a PDF printer first, and then printing the file to the printer.

Any of this commands work from the command line, and the file is printed ok:

```
cat <file.pdf> | acroread -toPostScript | lpr -P <printer name>

cat pdf2ps <file.pdf> | lpr -P <printer name>
```

but it doesn't (the printer does nothing), if I put them in the file opened when running "incrontab -e".

```
incrontab -e

/home/<user>/PDF IN_CLOSE_WRITE cat $@/$# | acroread -toPostScript | lpr -P <printer name>
```

save the file

Or

```
incrontab -e

/home/<user>/PDF IN_CLOSE_WRITE cat pdf2ps $@/$# | lpr -P <printer name>
```

save the file

Incron works ok with other commands, like cp.

On the other hand, the next two possible configurations for "incrontab -e" make the printer work, but with the problem I mentioned at the begining. Could be a problem with pipes?

```
/home/launion/PDF IN_CLOSE_WRITE /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice --invisible --norestore -pt <printer name> $@/$#

/home/launion/PDF IN_CLOSE_WRITE lpr -P <printer name> -o Resolution=600x600dpi -o PageSize=A4 -o Duplex=None $@/$#
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved the problem using a simple bash script (/usr/local/bin/print_pdf.sh), avoiding the use of pipes inside incrontab file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | acroread -toPostScript | lpr -P <printer name>
```

Execution permision for all users:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/print_pdf.sh
```

After that, as a normal user:

```
incrontab -e

/home/launion/PDF IN_CLOSE_WRITE print_pdf.sh $@/$#
```

save the file

Now, when printing to the virtual PDF printer, Toshiba printer will receive the file in PostScript and it will be printed ok.

I did not try with pdf2ps command but maybe it will work too.